# undefined method `stripe_customer_id=' for #<User:0x007f54fc63de10>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I want to pay bill via stripe account.I created my API key then I run the server it seems to following error

`undefined method 'stripe_customer_id=' for #<User:0x007f54fc63de10>`

thanks

Comment: provide please the User model

Comment: the SO (stackoverflow) isn't chat/forum engine, so please update your post, with a new data (if they are not an answer), and don't answer with them

Answer (score 0):

For this problem I have to use the follow solution it's working

I have to create a stripe.rb file in model

```
require "stripe"
Stripe.api_key = "xxxxxxxxxx"
STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error means that the class has no such instance assignment method. Generally, there are the two problem that can lead to the error:

1. Your active record has no proper field, in your case, `stripe_customer_id`. To fix it you shall add the field, and run the [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html). And then setup the relation to an other model, usually named `StripeCustomer`.

   ```
   class User
      belongs_to :stripe_customer
   end
   ```
2. Your `User` class(model) does not require the field `stripe_customer_id`, but you didn't setup the accessor methods, as follows:

   ```
   class User
      attr_accessor :stripe_customer_id
   end
   ```